# VBA delete sheet before saving

Tags: vba, excel

I have  the next VBA code:

```
Public Sub SaveAsA1()
    ThisFile = Range("B1:B31").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile
End Sub
```

I want to know how can i delete the sheet from where i take my names before saving.
My file have 3 sheets, 2 that i need to remain in there and one that i have to delete.
The last one is in there only for that range, for my VBA  scrip.
Please let me know if you can help me.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Questions including **`I need a code`** are off-topic for Stack Overflow. See [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sorry for that, i just modified

Comment: Still poor question with no effort shown. It's off-topic for here because as it stands it is not about programming

Comment: Ok, now i edited my question and i am more specific.

Comment: isn't an error raised on ThisFile = Range("B1:B31").Value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA offers the `.Delete` method which, when called on your Worksheet, will delete it.